# Easy way to fetch 2 years of months data even if we miss some months

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to fetch all 24 months displayed even if the months are missing with corresponding sales value as null. This is what i came up with. **As u can see we are missing id and custname. I need the id and custname with just sales as null, as dipicted in the below screenshot**

```
select CUSTNAME, reportdate, sales, mth
from (  select add_months(date '2017-01-01', level - 1) as mth 
  from dual 
  connect by level <= 24)mo
  left outer join oracle_tbl dc on mo.mth = trunc(reportdate, 'MM')
     order by mth
```

I have also tried the following and nothing just seem to work (i.e) giving nulls for custname and id which has missing dates

```
 WITH mydates AS (
    select LAST_DAY(add_months(date '2017-01-01', level - 1)) as mth, min_id,min_custname
  from (
  select min(id) as min_id, min(CUSTNAME) as min_custname
  from my_oracle_tbl 
  )
  connect by level <= 24)
  select
  nvl(t.id, a.min_id)id,
  nvl(t.CUSTNAME,a.min_custname)CUSTNAME, a.mth, t.sales
   from mydates a left join my_oracle_tbl t on a.mth= LAST_DAY(t.reporttdate)
  where
  t.id=12345;


  select CUSTNAME, reportdate, sales, mth
  from( SELECT CUSTNAME, reportdate, sales, mth FROM my_oracle_tbl
  WHERE id=123 )
 myTotals
       right outer join
       (select LAST_DAY(date '2017-01-01' + numtoyminterval(level-1,'month')) MonthName
          from dual
       connect by level <= 24) ALLMONTHS
       on( myTotals.mm = allmonths.MonthName )
```

[![This is how i get.. missing id and custname][1]][1]

[![this is what i need][2]][2]

Comment: Can you provide sample data and results?

Comment: @Rika updated above

Answer (score 1):

You haven't said exactly what is wrong, but you are ordering by a string value, so you will get January 2017, then January 2018, then February 2017...

Keep dates as actual dates until you need to display them in a fixed format (or let your client do that). That includes for comparison.

```
select dc.CUSTNAME, dc.reportdate, dc.sales, mo.mth
from (
  select add_months(date '2017-01-01', level - 1) as mth 
  from dual 
  connect by level <= 24
) mo
left outer join oracle_tbl dc on mo.mth = trunc(dc.reportdate, 'MM')
order by mo.mth
```

where `trunc(reportdate, 'MM')` truncates the report date to the first day of its month; or with a date range (which is more index-friendly):

```
select dc.CUSTNAME, dc.reportdate, dc.sales, mo.mth
from (
  select add_months(date '2017-01-01', level - 1) as mth 
  from dual 
  connect by level <= 24
) mo
left outer join oracle_tbl dc
on dc.reportdate >= mo.mth
and dc.reportdate < add_months(mo.mth, 1)
order by mo.mth
```

Either way you'll get `mth` as a date, which you can then format however you want for display - if you actually want to display it at all.

Comment: Thank you. The issue is that the above is missing ID as well. I need all attributes with all 24 months and null to the missing Sales months. I also tried creating a temp view for the 23 months and perform outer join b/w table and dates view, but doesn’t work. How do I get all values except sales repeated for the missing months

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we have the following tables: {1} DATES, containing the last day of all months that you need, and {2} SALES, containing sales for customers (not for every month).

```
create table dates ( month_end_date ) 
as
select add_months(date '2017-01-01', level - 1) - 1
from dual
connect by level <= 24 ; 

create table sales (customerid, custname, sales, date_of_sale ) 
as
select *
from (
  select
    case when mod( level, 3 ) = 0 then 1 end as customerid
  , case when mod( level, 3 ) = 0 then 'test' end
  , case when mod( level, 3 ) = 0 then trunc( dbms_random.value() * 10000 ) end
  , case when mod( level, 3 ) = 0 then add_months(date '2017-01-01', level - 1) end
  from dual connect by level <= 24
) 
where customerid is not null ;
```

SALES table

```
-- SALES colum: random values!
-- sales values recorded every third month
SQL> select * from sales ;

CUSTOMERID CUST      SALES DATE_OF_S
---------- ---- ---------- ---------
         1 test       5764 01-MAR-17
         1 test       3937 01-JUN-17
         1 test       9926 01-SEP-17
         1 test       3045 01-DEC-17
         1 test        598 01-MAR-18
         1 test        325 01-JUN-18
         1 test       2590 01-SEP-18
         1 test       5803 01-DEC-18

8 rows selected.
```

DATES table

```
SQL> select * from dates ;

MONTH_END
---------
31-DEC-16
31-JAN-17
28-FEB-17
31-MAR-17
30-APR-17
...
31-JUL-18
31-AUG-18
30-SEP-18
31-OCT-18
30-NOV-18

24 rows selected.
```

The following query should give you something to work from ... The CROSS JOIN gives you all combinations
of customerids + customernames and month_end_dates.  The LEFT JOIN outputs all the NULL values you need.  (Notice that we are calling LAST_DAY() in the join condition.)  You could also use "SELECT ... CONNECT BY ..." for generating all MONTH_END_DATEs ( as you have done in your own query )

```
select CM.customerid, CM.custname, S.sales, CM.month_end_date
from (
  select *
  from (
    ( select unique customerid, custname from sales )
    cross join
    ( select month_end_date from dates )  -- <- data could be "generated"
  ) 
) CM left join sales S on CM.month_end_date = last_day( S.date_of_sale ) 
order by CM.month_end_date
;
```

Result

```
CUSTOMERID CUST      SALES MONTH_END
---------- ---- ---------- ---------
         1 test NULL       31-DEC-16
         1 test NULL       31-JAN-17
         1 test NULL       28-FEB-17
         1 test       5764 31-MAR-17
         1 test NULL       30-APR-17
         1 test NULL       31-MAY-17
         1 test       3937 30-JUN-17
         1 test NULL       31-JUL-17
         1 test NULL       31-AUG-17
         1 test       9926 30-SEP-17
         1 test NULL       31-OCT-17
         1 test NULL       30-NOV-17
         1 test       3045 31-DEC-17
         1 test NULL       31-JAN-18
         1 test NULL       28-FEB-18
         1 test        598 31-MAR-18
         1 test NULL       30-APR-18
         1 test NULL       31-MAY-18
         1 test        325 30-JUN-18
         1 test NULL       31-JUL-18
         1 test NULL       31-AUG-18
         1 test       2590 30-SEP-18
         1 test NULL       31-OCT-18
         1 test NULL       30-NOV-18
-- caution:       sale for 01-DEC-18 "chopped off"
24 rows selected.
```

[dbfiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4efaac3ab2c5051578df92656a6560d1)

**EDIT (restrict the date range, filter by customer)**

For dealing with more than one customer, and narrowing the date range (of the result set), add a condition to the LEFT JOIN's ON clause, and then some more conditions to the WHERE clause eg

SALES (test) table CTAS

```
-- New SALES table for testing
-- 5 customers, 1 sale every 5 months (per customer)
create table sales (customerid, custname, sales, date_of_sale ) 
as
select *
from (
  select
    mod( level, 5 ) + 1
  , 'test' || to_char( mod( level, 5 ) + 1 )
  , trunc( dbms_random.value() * 10000 )
  , add_months(date '2017-01-01', level - 1)
  from dual connect by level <= 24
) 
;
```

SALES data

```
SQL> select * from sales;

CUSTOMERID  CUSTNAME  SALES  DATE_OF_SALE  
2           test2     5594   01-JAN-17     
3           test3     6398   01-FEB-17     
4           test4     2072   01-MAR-17     
5           test5     4269   01-APR-17     
1           test1     9435   01-MAY-17     
2           test2     6984   01-JUN-17     
3           test3     5735   01-JUL-17     
4           test4     9549   01-AUG-17     
5           test5     9686   01-SEP-17     
1           test1     9193   01-OCT-17     
2           test2     1702   01-NOV-17     
3           test3     8277   01-DEC-17     
4           test4     8235   01-JAN-18     
5           test5     7596   01-FEB-18     
1           test1     5507   01-MAR-18     
2           test2     6267   01-APR-18     
3           test3     5708   01-MAY-18     
4           test4     755    01-JUN-18     
5           test5     3966   01-JUL-18     
1           test1     5167   01-AUG-18     
2           test2     6819   01-SEP-18     
3           test3     9268   01-OCT-18     
4           test4     1844   01-NOV-18     
5           test5     1085   01-DEC-18     

24 rows selected.
```

Query

```
-- sales for customer (id) 3, between 30 Apr 2018 and 31 Dec 2018
select CM.customerid, CM.custname, S.sales, CM.month_end_date
from (
  select *
  from (
    ( select unique customerid, custname from sales )
    cross join
    ( select month_end_date from dates )
  ) 
) CM 
  left join sales S 
         on CM.month_end_date = last_day( S.date_of_sale )
           and CM.customerid = S.customerid  
where CM.customerid = 3
  and CM.month_end_date > date '2018-04-30'
  and CM.month_end_date < date '2018-12-31'
order by CM.month_end_date
;

-- result
CUSTOMERID  CUSTNAME  SALES  MONTH_END_DATE  
3           test3     5708   31-MAY-18       
3           test3     NULL   30-JUN-18       
3           test3     NULL   31-JUL-18       
3           test3     NULL   31-AUG-18       
3           test3     NULL   30-SEP-18       
3           test3     9268   31-OCT-18       
3           test3     NULL   30-NOV-18
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=cd171b3b1e1eef192ad1ae692c5d7717)

Comment: Thank you. But the above partiton by is resulting wrong results (1) it doesnt allow me to filter for a particular customer id and (2) it gives all available years beyond what is in our dates tables

Comment: @sunnybabau - If you cannot get the "partition by" to work, don't bother.  Please see the "edit":  the query should allow you to filter the results as required.

Comment: @sunnybabau - the outer join (whether LEFT or RIGHT) will not generate the missing dates.  That's why I suggested the combination of a CROSS JOIN with a left join.  Another example (just with a SALES table, but without a dedicated DATES table): https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=aac5897659d92b53662b3c7b8b052304